# Disabling link doesn't work with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have tried everything that possible, 6 stackoverflow answers.

```
        $('#link').bind('click.killlink',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

and a simple preventDefaults function on click without binding and more, but none of these works.
Why doesn't it work?

Basically, the links that I call updates every 10 seconds with a jquery ping.
So the php file (ajax) returns a table, with the links:

This is what it's returning.

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Survival Games A
                </td>
                <td>
                    0
                </td>
                <td>
                    Wilderness
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class='status_success'>Available</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a id='link' href='https://mywebsitelinkhere.com'><span class='button_join' id='a'>Join</span></a>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
```

I've tried using `.button_join` as click/bind and `#link` but nothing really work, absolutely none of these.

What is wrong there?

Comment: Use `.on()`, not `.bind()` and event delegation.

Comment: @dystroy I think it's event namespace - http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Answer (score 2):

The `#link` element must exist when you execute this code.

If the element doesn't exist, you may do this :

```
$(function(){
    $(document.body).on('click', '#link', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's on method.

```
$('#link').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```